# Cannot connect to remote database using mySQL on a form in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Trying to connect to a remote database on my hostinger.de account using VB.net. Connecting to the database using PHP on my hostinger.de website works just fine. Trying to connect via VB.net from desktop throws an error message:

> a network-related error occurred... Win32Exception: The network path was not found."

I double-checked the server path. It is exactly as mentioned in my php admin area. Connecting via MySQL workbench works fine.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim results As String

    myConn = New SqlConnection("server=sql588.main-hosting.eu;uid=u942496093_User1;database=u942496093_Test1;password=abcDEF123!")
    'myConn = New SqlConnection("server=145.14.151.51;uid=u942496093_User1;database=u942496093_Test1;password=abcDEF123!")

    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Vorname, Nachname FROM TestTabelle1"

    myConn.Open()

    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader

    Do While myReader.Read()
        results = results & myReader.GetString(0) & vbTab &
            myReader.GetString(1) & vbLf
    Loop

    MsgBox(results)

    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `SqlConnection`, etc. are a set of classes for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. You'll need to add an appropriate MySQL package via Nuget to talk to MySQL.

Comment: You ahve to use MySQL Connector. Download it here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/  then include it as library/dll in your project or try to get via Nuget.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I had searched the web and tried different things for hours and I was starting to get desperate...